# how to change the order services is loading in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i need to change the order services is loading. I have service with system status but sometimes it loading too late.How this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify the order, but you can specify what dependency has a service, and with this you shoul achieve the same result. Just open the service control manager ( here showing Messaging Service):
[image]

If you intend to do the same from API, try to [start from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681987%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, the question sounds like Sergey wants to do something else. He is complaining that his service is starting too late, i.e. he wants his service started before something else. If that something else is another service of his, sure he can add the first one as a dependency for the second one. If he cares about the order between arbitrary services, I think he's lost, as I don't think there is a way to affect that.

Comment: Oh and glancing at his other questions so far, it looks like he's developing some service that shall manipulate other applications - draw on other applications' windows, getting HDCs from other processes... so I would guess his problem is that his service is starting after something else which he then can't get control of any more, or the like.

Comment: @Mephane true, if so, the link point to the service control manager api, so maybe the reply be useful as well.